# Tensorflow 2.0 Cuda 10.0 install

Tags: nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

I am following the steps [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/12/09/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-0-on-ubuntu/). I am currently at this step:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir installers
$ cd installers/
$ wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux
$ mv cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux.run
$ chmod +x cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux.run
$ sudo ./cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux.run --override
```

The last step specifically. Once I agree to install everything I am getting this error message:

```
Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
The driver installation has failed due to an unknown error. Please consult the driver installation log located at /var/log/nvidia-installer.log.

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Installation Failed
Toolkit:  Installation skipped
Samples:  Installation skipped
```

I have tried numerous methods to doing this and I am perplexed by the difficulty. I was told that using Linux Ubuntu for deep learning development is the way to go but I am finding this ridiculous to say the least.

Comment: Have you looked in the log ("*Please consult the driver installation log located at /var/log/nvidia-installer.log.*")  As we cannot see the log, how are we to know the problem, you also didn't provide your Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During the installation it will ask you if you want to install the drivers for your GPU, just write no and proceed to install ONLY THE CUDA TOOLKIT, otherwise you'll get this error message.